# compareTo with generic arguments is giving warning

Tags: java, generics, comparison

I want to compare two arguments in less method which are of type Comparable. But if I use comapreTo it is giving me error in type casting:

```
private boolean less(Comparable<T> u, Comparable<T> v) {
    return u.compareTo(v) < 0;
}
```

I fixed the issue by type casting the argument passed into compareTo. But still it is giving me warning (Type safety: Unchecked cast from Comparable to T). Why is it so. Am I doing something wrong. What is the best way to achieve this.

```
private boolean less(Comparable<T> u, Comparable<T> v) {
    return u.compareTo((T) v) < 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing context, but shouldn't it be more like `private boolean less(Comparable<T> u, T v) {`?  Since you're trying to compare `U` to `V` which are types of `T` ...?

Comment: T extends Comparable and I want to compare two parameters which are of type Comparable.

Comment: But [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) only defines a single method `compareTo(T)`. The value you are comparing needs to be of the same type that `Comparable` expects. You method would actually look more like `private <T extends Comparable> boolean less(Comparable<T> u, T v) {`?!?  To me, this makes no sense

Comment: I have an array of Comparable<T> objects how would i compare them without this. Can you suggest me?

Comment: I think you're confusing the issue.  You have an array of `Comparable<T>`, so I assume you have an instance of `T` you want to compare each element in the array against?  Then `private boolean less(Comparable<T> u, T v) {` would work

Comment: I have a generic method in which I don't have instance of T, I have instance of Comaprable<T> arr[] :(, The code is big so I cannot post the complete code.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure you have much of a choice.  The API requirements of `Comparable` state that you must pass `T` to `compareTo`, where `Comparable<T>` clearly is not an instance of `T`.  You might be able to use something like `private static <T extends Comparable> boolean less(T u, T v) {`, but this will only solve your compiler issues, I don't think it's really logically correct (`compare(Comparable<T>`)? Maybe an array of `T<? extends Comparable>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `u` has type `Comparable<T>`, `u.compareTo()` takes a `T`. You're passing it `v`, a `Comparable<T>`, which is not compatible.

You might be assuming in your mind that a type that implements `Comparable` is comparable to itself. But there is no such requirement on a technical level. It's perfectly legal for me to make a type `Foo`, that is `Comparable<Bar>`, i.e. it compares to `Bar`, where `Foo` and `Bar` are completely unrelated. Trying to pass a `Foo` into a `Foo` object's `compareTo` will crash.

If you want to make a constraint that the two arguments are of the same type which is comparable to itself, you would do something like

```
private <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean less(T u, T v) {
    return u.compareTo(v) < 0;
}
```

However, for the purposes of this function, the constraint that the two arguments are of the same type is not technically necessary (although it should be true in all normal use cases). And in generics we always want to use the least restrictive bound possible, which is, as other answers have mentioned,

```
private <T> boolean less(Comparable<T> u, T v) {
    return u.compareTo(v) < 0;
}
```

In your comments, you mentioned you are comparing elements from a `Comparable<T>[]`. That is not a type of array that allows you to compare elements from. You just know that it's an array of elements that are comparable to a certain `T`, but not comparable to themselves. Much more useful would be to have a `T[]`, where `T` has a bound that it is comparable to itself:

```
class Whatever<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    //...
    T[] yourArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial error is correct, and the warning is correct to: your trick is very unsafe: you can't cast v to T.

Because your method takestwo parameters u and v, each one is an instance of a class, which implements compareTo ( some instance of T).

precisely: u can compare to T, v can compare to T.

But, inside, you want to compare u and v. There is absolutely no garantee you can do it.

This, for example, is correct:

```
private static <X> boolean less(Comparable<X> u, X v)
    {
    return u.compareTo(v) < 0;
    }
```